# can't connect a webservice to MOSS 2010

Tags: .net, wcf, webservice-client, sharepoint-workflow

I have a client application (workflow designer) which have to publish a workflow on Sharepoint 2010.
Since my application is developped in .NET 4.5 and MOSS 2010 can't deal with that version (as it's mentionned in many forums like on this link http://demiliani.com/blog/archive/2009/11/19/6569.aspx or this one http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/08/21/net-4-with-sharepoint-foundation-2010/) I'm trying to use a  WCF web service to connect my workflow to the sharepoint site with the following code:

public SPWorkflowTemplate GetSite(string name,string url)
        {

```
        SPWorkflowTemplate suivi = null;

         SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {

            SPSite mySite = new SPSite(url);

        SPWeb myWeb = mySite.OpenWeb("WPrs");
        suivi = myWeb.WorkflowTemplates.GetTemplateByName(name, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
});
        return suivi;
    }
```

when i try to publish a workflow with my application I get this exception:

Fault Exception 1 was unhandled

The Web application at `http://localhost:91/` could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.

But I am sure that the URL is correct so does anyone can help me...?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) WCF must be hosted on the SharePoint server machine.

2) It must be running on .Net 3.5 and target AnyCpu or x64.

3) It must be running in an Application Pool/WAS Service Account which Identity has permissions to the SharePoint site.

Comment: I have already checked those points...
I made another WCF web service and now I Have this error: 

FaultException 1 was unhandled
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {BDEADF26-C265-11D0-BCED-00A0C90AB50F} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

this is weird because when I use this webservice to do a simple a+b operation, it works

Comment: googling say that it's related to step 2 (http://rhythmiccoding.blogspot.ru/2010/06/retrieving-com-class-factory-for.html)

Comment: + check SP dll referenced from 14 hive and allow 32bit apps in app pool

Comment: already googled and checked all that...would migrating to sharepoint 2013 solve the problem?